# Italian professional word and sentence list

Tags: resource-request, italian

I found [this](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_B1_Wortliste.pdf) excellent German CEFR level B1 word and sentence list from the Goethe Institut.

Is there a similar free file available for **Italian**? Anywhere from A2-B2 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following resources:

- The *Vocabulary Index* on the *OnlineItalianClub* website where you can find different vocabulary topic from A1 to C2 level (https://onlineitalianclub.com/italian-vocabulary-lists-and-exercises/).
- The *Books4Languages* free textbook “*Italian Vocabulary A2 Level*” (https://open.books4languages.com/italian-a2-vocabulary/).
- The *Learn Italian Vocabulary* section (mainly from A1 to B1 level) on the *Lingolex* website (https://lingolex.com/italian/).